# Conflict when i save my file(EsLint + Prittier formater)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, prettier-vscode

I have that arrow function
[image]

I have this error in my file. To fix this error, I can return it like this => {return ...}, or just put parentheses around what is inside the arrow function

When I do that the error disappears, but if I save the file it goes back to the way it is in the photo. Where do I remove this setting?

If I return like this => {return ...} or => ( ), I would like it to stay, not for it to remove the parentheses or change the arrow function with curly braces to parentheses

Obs: Put // eslint-disable-next-line no-confusing-arrow is not an option

Answer (score 0):

You might try replacing your ? conditionals with ||

[ESLint `no-confusing-arrow` "--fix" formatting conflict on save, with Prettier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279433/eslint-no-confusing-arrow-fix-formatting-conflict-on-save-with-prettier)

Comment: I don't want to disable the rule, I want to resolve my conflict.

Comment: Then what is your question - if there's a way to format that code that will appease both eslint and prettier despite their conflicting rules?

Comment: edited my answer with a possible solution mentioned on another question about this same issue